# Is there much fuzz hooking BlueSMiRF Silver to Netduino?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, netduino

I have no experience with soldering other then watching a couple of youtube vidz, would it be much fuzz getting [BlueSMiRF](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10269) to work with my Netdiuno (soldering-wize)?

I guess I also would need some [SMD Headers](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9015)

Comment: I might be missing something, but what do you mean by fuzz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A header would be the usual way to plug one board on top of another one. Not the one you link to, that's for soldering flat on a PCB, you would need [straight pin headers](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/87220-6/A26550-ND/353072); both boards are through-hole.

But that requires that the pinout of both boards is the same, and having a look at the Netduino board that seems unlikely: Netduino seems to have power connections together, and I/O together.

[image]

You'll need both for the BlueSMiRF, so that won't do.

[This](http://www.adafruit.com/products/759) is a solution:

[image]

You can connect pins as required, and you don't need the headers. If the Netduino is supplied with the blue sockets as on the image they'll still be removable, otherwise you'll have to solder them. If you want them removable and the Netduino doesn't have the sockets, there are also female-female versions of the wires, which you would plug onto a header.